# Simplify procedure with multiple if condition

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I am new and have a procedure which needs to be simplified.
It has multiple if and inserts and I want to simplify it.

```sql
BEGIN

IF oldProductType IS NOT NULL AND PRODUCTTYPE != oldProductType THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Product Type', oldProductType, PRODUCTTYPE, '');

UPDATE ab_project SET product_type = PRODUCTTYPE where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldProgramManager IS NOT NULL AND PROGRAMMANAGER != oldProgramManager THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Program Manager', oldProgramManager, PROGRAMMANAGER, '');

          UPDATE ab_project SET program_manager = PROGRAMMANAGER where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldProductManager IS NOT NULL AND PRODUCTMANAGER != oldProductManager THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Product Manager', oldProductManager, PRODUCTMANAGER, '');

          UPDATE ab_project SET product_manager = PRODUCTMANAGER where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldProductName IS NOT NULL AND PRODUCTNAME != oldProductName THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Product Name', oldProductName, PRODUCTNAME, '');

            UPDATE ab_project SET product_name = PRODUCTNAME where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldDescription IS NOT NULL AND PRODUCTDESCRIPTION != oldDescription THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Product Description', oldDescription, PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, '');

            UPDATE ab_project SET product_description = PRODUCTDESCRIPTION where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldRequestType IS NOT NULL AND REQUESTTYPE != oldRequestType THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Request Type', oldRequestType, REQUESTTYPE, '');

           UPDATE ab_project SET request_type = REQUESTTYPE where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldOtherProduct IS NOT NULL AND OTHERPRODUCT != oldOtherProduct THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Other Product', oldOtherProduct, OTHERPRODUCT, '');

          UPDATE ab_project SET Other_Product = OTHERPRODUCT where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldBusinessRationale IS NOT NULL AND BUSINESSRATIONALE != oldBusinessRationale THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Business Rationale', oldBusinessRationale, BUSINESSRATIONALE, '');

            UPDATE ab_project SET business_rationale = BUSINESSRATIONALE where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF oldSoftwareDependency IS NOT NULL AND SOFTWAREDEPENDENCY != oldSoftwareDependency THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Software Dependency', oldSoftwareDependency, SOFTWAREDEPENDENCY, '');

           UPDATE ab_project SET software_dependency = SOFTWAREDEPENDENCY where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF OldOtherDependency IS NOT NULL AND OTHERDEPENDENCY != OldOtherDependency THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Other Dependency', OldOtherDependency, OTHERDEPENDENCY, '');

              UPDATE ab_project SET other_dependency = OTHERDEPENDENCY where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;

IF OldReleaseCycleID IS NOT NULL AND RELEASECYCLEID != OldReleaseCycleID THEN

groupIdVal := prcChangeGroupIdSeq.NEXTVAL;

INSERT INTO CHANGE_GROUP VALUES(groupIdVal,projectid,user_id,SYSDATE);

 insert into change_log (id, groupId, type, field, oldvalue, newvalue, fieldtypeid) 
          values (prcChangeLogIdSeq.NEXTVAL, groupIdVal, 'project', 'Release Cycle ID', OldReleaseCycleID, RELEASECYCLEID, '');

             UPDATE ab_project SET release_cycle_id = RELEASECYCLEID where project_id = PROJECTID;

END IF;


commit;
exception
when others then
    raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' - Error - '||SQLERRM);
end;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "optimization" here?  Normally, that would refer to performance which would imply that you have a performance problem here.  If that's the case, what have you done to profile the code?  What are the query plans for the various statements?  Without table and index definitions, it would appear that everything is doing single-row insert and update operations which ought to be pretty quick.  You could potentially replace the separate `ab_project` updates with a single one, assuming multiple `if` statements can be true at the same time, but that shouldn't be a huge improvement.

Comment: But maybe you're not using "optimization" in the normal sense and you're really asking if the procedure can be simplified/ refactored?

Comment: Yes maybe I didn't use the right word. Since, I am new, I want to know if there is a better way to write this piece of code

Comment: OK.  Then can you explain what the procedure is doing and why?  For example, every `if` statement is doing an identical insert into `change_group`.  So if 6 `if` statements are all true, you're going to get 6 new rows in `change_group` with the same data other than, I assume, the sequence-generated primary key.  It seems unlikely that is useful.  I would think that you'd want a single `update` of `ab_project` rather than having that in each `if` statement unless there is some reason that you really want the same row to get updated several times potentially.

Comment: Your exception handler appears to be doing nothing useful and is just hiding information about the error stack where an error actually occurred as well.  I'd get rid of that entirely unless you can actually add value in the exception you raise.

Comment: If you edit the question, please be careful to retain the formatting that Sayan added for you so that your code is readable.

Comment: The code checks if there is any change done to six fields and logs into an audit table with new and old values for tracking. Each section checks for one field if there is any change. I realized that my code is a simple one hence exception isn't required, will remove it. Thanks!

Comment: The audit table, I assume, is `change_log`.  Those `insert` statements make sense if we make some assumptions about the structure of that table.  What is the purpose of the inserts into `change_group`?  Do you really want potentially 11 identical inserts in that table?  If so, why?  Is there a reason that you're doing separate updates on `ab_project` rather than doing a single `update`?

Comment: I am trying to capture any changes/updates to fields on my project. For each change, I am entering a record with field name, old value, new value into change_log table. Change group contains information about the project id and user who modified the data

Comment: Yes single update can be done rather than doing multiple updates and I would make the changes. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: But if someone updates 11 fields, there are going to be 11 mostly identical rows in `change_group`.  If you want the `user_id` and date of the change, it would seem to make sense to add those to `change_log` instead rather than having them in separate tables.

Comment: Thanks again! Makes sense and I have made changes and moved it to top of the code to exeute just once.

Answer (score 0):

CASE is probably what you want